# Cakephp 3 : How to give condition in get method?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to give a condition in `cakephp` 3 get method, where data will fetch by foreign id not primary key. Here I have tried below code:

```
$eventPasswordAll = $this->EventPasswordAll->get($id, [
            'conditions'  => ['event_id'=>$id],
            'contain'     => ['Events']
]);
```

But it showing me data according to `id(primary key)`, not by `event_id`. How I add this condition in get methods like where `event_id=my get id` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use [`get`](https://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#_get), use [`find`](https://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#_find). According to [CakePHP 3.0 Table API](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html), the [`get`](https://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#_get) method:

> Returns a single record after finding it by its **primary key**, if no record is found this method throws an exception.

You need to use [`find`](https://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#_find):

```
$eventPasswordAll = $this->EventPasswordAll->find('all', [  // or 'first'
    'conditions' => ['event_id' => $id],
    'contain'    => ['Events']
]);
// or
$eventPasswordAll = $this->EventPasswordAll->find()
    ->where(['event_id' => $id])
    ->contain(['Events']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you want to get the id and the userid..

```
$this->loadModel('Jobapplications');
$application = $this->Jobapplications->find('all', [ 
  'conditions' => ['id' => $id, 'user_id' => $user_id]
]);
$application = $application->first();
```